# Cursor Bar for selection

Tags: javascript, php, html

i don't the name of this "function".
I just want to know what is this and how can i do it :

[image]

Comment: You mean the html input tag with the type range: http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_input_range ?!

Comment: it's called gerald, though she is female

Comment: Thats not php. Maybe its a canvas. Look at the code behind it

Comment: range slider. google "jquery range slider"